# using apache ant to validate Javsacsript syntax

Tags: java, javascript, ant, rhino

My Java web app contains java files for the back-end and javascript files for the front-end.  I have an ant script that compiles the java code and creates and deploys a war file (which contains the js files and other assets).

Additionally, I would like the ant script to validate that the js has correct syntax.  If someone accidentally breaks the js by deleting a curly brace or semicolon, I want to the ant script to tell me.

I'm using Java 7, so Rhino is already available in the jdk.

How would I set up an ant task that uses Rhino to load up a javascript file and return an error code if Rhino was unable to parse the javascript file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had good experience using WRO4J to lint and minify my js resources.

http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/

Answer (score 0):

Please check https://github.com/philmander/ant-jshint looks promising to automate JShint with Apache Ant.

check http://www.jshint.com/platforms/